# The list is not printing through the printList(), what i'm doing wrong here?

Tags: c++11, stl

See my code below.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// a global variable
std::list<int>myList;

void addToList(int max, int interval)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if( (i % interval) == 0) myList.push_back(i);
    }
}

void printList()
{
    for (std::list<int>::iterator itr = myList.begin(), end_itr = myList.end(); itr != end_itr; ++itr ) 
    {
        cout << *itr << ",";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int max = 100;

    std::thread t1(addToList, max, 1);
    std::thread t2(addToList, max, 10);
    std::thread t3(printList);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Thread t3(printList)is not printing the list. Empty output is coming. Is it because  t3 is executing first before inserting any item in the list? What is the reason for this?

Comment: Try printing only after joining the other threads, plus you should probably use a mutex if you have two threads accessing the same list

Answer (score 0):

If you spin up threads like that there's no guarantee which of them will execute or complete first.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing 3 threads which have different tasks to do:

- The first 2 threads perform the the function **addToList**, which have a for for **n** times.
- The third thread is executing the function **printList**.

In this case **printList** doesn't wait **t1** and **t2** have finished. At the moment to read the list (**t3*) **t1** and **t2** haven't added anything to the list.

```
t1 
|-- loop[0 max]{ / calculate interval / adding number at the end of list} -->[End of t1]
t2 
|-- loop[0 max]{ / calculate interval / adding number at the end of list} -->[End of t2]
t3 
|-- Rd & Prnt -->[End of t3]
                ^                                                            ^
                |                                                            | 
            t3 finished before t1 and t2                              Possible end of the threads t1 and t2 (*)
```

To avoid this situation **t3** must wait until **t1** and **t2** are finished.

```
int main()
{
    int max = 100;

    std::thread t1(addToList, max, 1);
    std::thread t2(addToList, max, 10);


    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::thread t3(printList);
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}



t1 
|-- loop[0 max]{ / calculate interval / adding number at the end of list} -->[End of t1]
t2 
|-- loop[0 max]{ / calculate interval / adding number at the end of list} -->[End of t2]
                                                                             t3 
                                                                             |-- Rd & Prnt -->[End of t3]
```

Considere that **t1** and **t2** will not start at the same time, i represented it for practical purposes.